# How do I display database calls from Controller into view, to be viewed in HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was handed a project from someone else, it's in Ruby On Rails, which I know VERY LITTLE.  Basically, there is an EXPORT button, that the user clicks to send data to a CSV. I am tasked with sending this data to the view to be seen in HTML. (Thinking I could use dataTables).  I have tried following examples, such as:

```
@example = StudentGroup.where(survey_id: @survey.id).order("groupNum")
```

and then using `<%= @example %>` in the view just to see the data and I get nothing.  (Also extremely new to MySQL).  I'll post the method, if ANYONE can help me, I'd very much appreciate it.

```
      def download_results
if (user_signed_in?)
else
  redirect_to new_user_session_path
end
@survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_to_view])
filename = @survey.name + " - " + Date.today.to_formatted_s(:short)
require "csv"

CSV.open(@survey.name+".csv", "wb") do |csv|
  csv << [filename]

  StudentGroup.where(survey_id: @survey.id).order("groupNum")

  csv << []
  csv << ["Summarized Results"]
  csv << ["UCA","Group Number","Criteria 1","Criteria 2","Criteria 3","Criteria 4","Criteria 5","Criteria 6","Criteria 7","Criteria 8","Overall Team Contribution","Average(Would Work With Again)","Average(C1..C8)","Overall Team Contribution MINUS Average(C1..C9)"]


  questions = @survey.questions
  numQuestions = 0
   questions.each do |q|
    if(q.question_type != 2 && q.question_type != 4)
      numQuestions = numQuestions+1
    end
  end

  groups.each do |g|


    answersCount = Answer.where(student_group_id: g.id).count
    if(answersCount == numQuestions && answersCount != 0)

      othersInGroup = StudentGroup.where(groupNum: g.groupNum, survey_id: @survey.id).order("groupNum")
      size = othersInGroup.count-1
      arr = []

      criteria = SurveyQuestionDatum.where("number > 24 AND number < 35")
      multiAvg = 0
      teamCont = 0
      criteria.each do |c|
        avg = 0
        othersInGroup.each do |o|
          a = Answer.where(survey_question_datum_id: c.id, student_group_id: o.id).first
          if(o.uca != g.uca)
            if(a.nil?)
              size = size-1
            else
              avg = avg + a.answer[g.uca].to_i
            end
          end
        end
        avg = avg.to_f/size
        if(c.number == 33)
          teamCont = avg
        end
        if(c.number < 33)
          multiAvg = multiAvg+avg
        end
        arr << avg
      end
      multiAvg = multiAvg.to_f/8
      arr << multiAvg
      arr << teamCont-multiAvg

      arr.insert(0,g.uca, g.groupNum)
      csv << arr
    end
  end

  csv << []
  csv << []
  csv << ["Raw Student Answers"]

  groups = StudentGroup.where(survey_id: @survey.id).order("groupNum")

  size = groups.count
  csv << ["UCA", "F-Number", "Group Number"]
  groups.each do |g|

    answersCount = Answer.where(student_group_id: g.id).count
    if(answersCount == numQuestions && answersCount != 0)
    othersInGroup = StudentGroup.where(groupNum: g.groupNum, survey_id: @survey.id).order("groupNum")

    csv << []

    csv << [g.uca, g.FNum, g.groupNum]
    answers = Answer.where(student_group_id: g.id)
    csv << ["Question Number", "Question", "Answer"]
    answers.each do |a|
      datum = a.survey_question_datum
      question = datum.question
    #question_types = {"0" => "short", "1" => "paragraph",
    #2" => "title", "3" => "fivept", "4" => "fixed",
    #5" =>"ranking", "6"=>"tenpoints","7"=>"hundredpoints"}

      ansText = ""
      if(question.question_type == 0)
        ansText = a.answer
      elsif (question.question_type == 1)
        if(question.rule == 'perMember')
          othersInGroup.each do |o|
            ansText = ansText+"#{o.uca},#{a.answer[o.uca]},"
          end
        elsif(question.rule == 'default')
          ansText = a.answer
        end
      else (question.question_type == 3)
        othersInGroup.each do |o|
          ansText = ansText+"#{o.uca},#{a.answer[o.uca]},"
        end
      end
      ansText = ansText.chomp(',')
      ansText = ansText.split(',')
      ansText.insert(0,datum.number,question.question_text)

      csv << ansText

    end
  end
  end
end
send_file(@survey.name+".csv", :filename => filename+".csv")


end
```

Comment: this is a rather basic rails question so you might want to do some more research.  Also, please add some additional information to your question such as what you do see, what errors you are getting if any, and the some of your code.  In the code that you've posted :  
send_file(@survey.name+".csv", :filename => filename+".csv")  sends the file and doesn't present a view.  What does your code look like?

Comment: I appreciate your comment.  As far as what I see, I only have the code given, I am not sure how to view in HTML.  I have looked for a few hours and the only answers I've seen tell me to create a variable in the controller, @example, and then call it in the view to display the data.  Which I cannot replicate.  I apologize this is a basic question, I've never worked with Ruby before.   The send_file(@survey.name+".csv", :filename => filename+".csv") just prints the data to a CSV.

Comment: Really bad formatting of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new controller action.  Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Create an index (or show, or whatever you want to call it, maybe example) action.  Make sure it is in your routes.
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-route-for-comments

do not use the download_results code.

set your @example variable the way you were trying to do.

create a view for your index action

add the data to your index view.

If you put code in your download_results method (action) it will never get rendered because of the send_file method call.

Did you create a brand new controller / action / view? Did you use generators?  Have you really practiced doing this setup exactly the way the examples, videos, tutorials say to do it?  If you have, you have seen how all the pieces (models, controllers, actions, views) come together.  You should have seen how render statements come into play.  Do that, exactly as the tutorials say to do it and you will get the idea.

If you want to use the same content that the download action uses, refactor the code to extract a method that is used both actions.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to `respond_to` part, check the docs.

```
send_file(@survey.name+".csv", :filename => filename+".csv")
```

Your code above simply means you click the button, the controller will respond you with a csv file. So, if you want a html, the controller should be able to respond to html as well.

Comment: I have been trying to do this all morning, and I've been doing examples.  Every tutorial I watch, I replicate the process, but do not get anything to show in view.  In controller, @example = "my example", in view <%= "Message from controller : #{@example}" %>
And the only thing that populates is "Message from controller".